override an interface method containing ellipsis with an universal reference in c++
I would like to override an interface method which contains an ellipsis with a template method. I wonder if this is possible.
Imagine following:
class MyInterface
{
  public:
  virtual void myMethod(int i, const char* fmt, ...) = 0;
};

class MyMock: public MyInterface
{
  template< typename ...Args >
  void myMethod(int i, const char* fmt, Args&&... args) override
  {
    //use ellipsis expressions here

  }
};

When I do this I get the following error:
C++ function modifier (override) does not apply to member template declaration

It's not possible. Templates cannot be virtual and regular ellipsis ... is not the same thing as template parameter pack.

is this an attempt to create a virtual templated member function? (you can't) Or what else is the underlying problem? Or just curiosity?

the problem is I want to utilize cpp language benefits instead of using old c style functions

Yes, you can do that (I've done this myself, for runtime checking on C-style format strings obtained from a string-file with translations, against the types actually provided in the call). It just can't be virtual; you'd have to rearrange your interface accordingly (like having a non-virtual template that formats the string, and only passes the final string into a virtual function for actual handling). Still, not a fan of C-style format strings, frankly.

"the problem is I want to utilize cpp language benefits instead of using old c style functions" not quite. The problem is that you are mixing a c feature (which doesnt have virtual methods nor templates) with c++ features. I suppose you could use C++ instead of C, but what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Ok, maybe this is more open: I would like to perfect forward the ellipsis arguments to snprintf function. I don't want to use old c style variadic arguments.

As @Yksisarvinen says, you can't. Templates can't be virtual. C style varargs is a kind of type-erasure, which is why it can be virtual
